# Why was Mossador afraid of death?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In the new season of *Game of Thrones* we see the former slave Mossador being executed. Before he dies he pleads for his life. Is this inconsistent with the people of the free cities' behaviour? So as we all know, the "motto" of the people of the free cities is "Valar Morghulis" which is high Valyrian (I think) for "all men must die". When Danaerys asks Missandei if she fears death she simply answers, "Valar morghulis". The people of Yunkai especially seem to widely accept the fact that they will die and try to enjoy themselves as much as possible without thinking of consequence, Daario Naharas being a good example.

So with all that information wouldn't that mean that by that time, Mossador would have accepted his fate and faced it with dignity like every other person from the free cities does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break this apart to a few bullet points:

- Meereen is *not* one of the Free Cities. The term the Free Cities is given to a number of cities that freed themselves from Valyrian rule. They are: Braavos, Volantis, Pentos, Lys, Qohor, Norvos, Tyrosh, Lorath and Myr. Meereen, on the other hand is one of the Slaver Cities, all that remains of the Ghiscari Empire (destroyed by Valyria). The other two being Astapor and Yunkai.
- "Valar Morghulis" is simply a customary saying in Essos, and doesn't mean that the one who says it is not afraid of death, only that he accepts that death comes to all.
- The god who is most connected to this saying is The Many Faced God, and most people in Essos don't really worship him or ask him for aid until the very end of their life when they have finally "accepted" death.

Comment: In addition to that he of course *had* to fear his death that much to make the decision to kill him especially hard for Denaerys. Similar to the excution Jon Snow has to order as one of his first actions as boss of the wall (or whatever that's called).

Comment: I had considered that maybe Meereen was not a free city. Thanks ou for confirming it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, the title is the awesome "Lord Commander" and I only mention it as it is one of the coolest in the series, almost as nice as "The Sword of the Morning" or "The Prince that was Promised"

Answer (score 5):

Not every person is the same from a particular region or group. Some people value their life. Or most of them says "Valar Morghulis", does not mean no one there is afraid of dying. 
In our world, also every region has different kinds of people. similarly in the Game of Thrones universe all kinds of people are present everywhere. Not every northerner is a very respectful and righteous person like the Starks, some are Theon and Boltons. Similary, Littlefinger lived most of his childhood and youth with the Tullys but he dosn't share single characteristics with them. Even not every Lannister sharing blood are same.

Comment: That doesn't excactly answer the question but it's still an interesting point.